Relationship between function inequalities and their integrals
I'm assuming that if $f(x) > g(x)$ on the interval $[a, b]$, it holds that:
$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx>\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx?
$
Would this also mean that, if an antiderivative $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ could be readily found, $ F(x)>G(x) $ on $[a, b]$ assuming the same constant of integration?
